# ApplicationId conditioned by build type and flavour dimension

Tags: android, gradle

I have an application which has 2 flavour dimensions. First dimension, lets call it "brand" has two types:
"strawberry", "cyan"

Both have different applicationIds, but we can focus only on one of those. Lets say "cyan" has applicationId "com.cyan.app".

The second flavour dimension is called say "environment". It has two values:
"prod", "test".

I also have two build types:
"debug", "release"

Now what I'm interested in, is how can I go about configuring the gradle script such that whenever I'm building debug versions there will be applicationIdSuffix which will contain both "debug" string and environment name string. So in the above example it would be:
com.cyan.app.debug.prod and com.cyan.app.debug.test

But if I build release version of an app I want to leave the main applicationId, so com.cyan.app, no matter the environment flavour.

Is there any way I can achieve that with gradle and android gradle plugin?

Comment: `environment` is not a product flavor dimension, IMHO. Either `prod`=`release` and `test`=`debug` as build types, or `prod` and `test` are just other custom build types. Why do you think that `environment` should be a product flavor dimension?

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer and taking the time. Second of all, can we please stick to the topic? Lets call the dimensions "dimension_1" and "dimension_2" and the variants "variant_1", "variant_2" etc. How does it matter to the topic or the question what the dimensions are for? IMHO it's irrelevant to the question. The answer is either it's possible or not. If someone does indeed know the answer how to achieve what I ask I would greatly appriciate it.

Comment: "Second of all, can we please stick to the topic?" -- I was sticking to the topic, where the topic was "how can I get the applicationId values that I want", which would be simpler in this case if you did not have multiple flavor dimensions. I apologize for trying to be of assistance, and I will take steps to ensure that I do not do so in the future.

Comment: I'm not a conflict person so I will not try to fight with you over your answer. Like I've said I appriciate you taking the time even though you could not help me with the exact problem I presented. If anybody else knows how to do what I'm seeking for in gradle with conjunction with android gradle plugin I will be very thankfull. Just to clarify I'm not looking for a solution that will involve simplifying my case. That does not interest me. I want to find a solution for the exact case I presented, so multiple build types and multiple flavor dimensions (with multiple flavors).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I've sit down during the weekend and was able to achieve that (and more). Sharing here so that others can benefit who would like to achieve the same thing as I posted in the question.

So first of all we have to attach ourselves to the applicationVariants.all task like so:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
  //We tweak the package name and application name depending on the variants (so that we can have multiple applications installed on the phone, depending on the 
  tweakPackageName(variant);
  replaceInManifest(variant, 'android:label=\"@string/app_name\"', 'android:label=\"@string/
}
```

I've separated the logic to other methods so that the code is not clogged. The tweakPackageName method looks pretty simple (as it turned out):

```
/**
 * Method that alters the package name in order to have many different variants of application installed simultanously on a device.
 */
ext.tweakPackageName = { variant ->
  def envFlavor = getFlavorOfDimension(variant, flavorDimEnvironmentName);
  variant.mergedFlavor.applicationId = variant.mergedFlavor.applicationId + ".${envFlavor.name.toLowerCase()}";
}
```

getFlavorOfDimension is a simple method to get the flavor of particular dimension I'm interested in (not a biggie so I won't spam with this code here). When we get the flavor we add it to the package name of the mergedFlavor object and we're done.

I also managed to not only change the package name but also to dynamically change the application launcher name, but there are plenty of solutions of that on StackOverflow so I won't be redundant here. All in all the solution to alter the package name works. Hopefully it will help someone like it helped me.